# using GetObject, the memory stream returned is null while GetObjectSaveToFile returns proper file

Tags: .net, sdk, rackspace, cloudfiles

Rackspace .NET cloudifles API, the GetObjectSaveToFile method gets the file and save it properly in the specified location, but when using GetObject method, if i save the memorystream returned, the file is filled with bunch of nulls.

```
var cloudFilesProvider = new CloudFilesProvider(cloudIdentity);
cloudFilesProvider.GetObjectSaveToFile(inIntStoreID.ToString(), @"C:\EnetData\Development\Sanbox\OpenStack\OpenStackConsole\testImages\", inStrFileName);
```

works fine. but when i try

```
System.IO.Stream outputStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
cloudFilesProvider.GetObject(inIntStoreID.ToString(), inStrFileName, outputStream);
FileStream file = new FileStream(strSrcFilePath, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
byte[] bytes = new byte[outputStream.Length];
outputStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)outputStream.Length);
file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
file.Close();
outputStream.Close();
```

i get a file with bunch of nulls in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the secret to your problem lies in the return value of `outputStream.Read` - which is likely returning 0.

I would try the following code instead:

```
using (System.IO.Stream outputStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    cloudFilesProvider.GetObject(inIntStoreID.ToString(), inStrFileName, outputStream);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[outputStream.Length];
    outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    int length = outputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    if (length < bytes.Length)
        Array.Resize(ref bytes, length);

    File.WriteAllBytes(strSrcFilePath, bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that using the IO.SeekOrigin.Begin does work.
So I can define a class which has a byte array:-

```
 public class RackspaceStream
 {
    private  byte[] _bytes;

    public byte[] Bytes 
    {
        get { return _bytes; }
        set { _bytes = value; }
    }
    // other properties as needed
}
```

and use code very similar to the post above to assign the bytes from the output stream to it.

```
    public RackspaceStream DownloadFileToByteStream(string containerName, string cloudObjectName)
    {
        RackspaceStream rsStream = new RackspaceStream();
        try
        {
            CloudFilesProvider cfp = GetCloudFilesProvider();

            using (System.IO.Stream outputStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                cfp.GetObject(containerName, cloudObjectName, outputStream);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[outputStream.Length];
                outputStream.Seek (0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

                int length = outputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                if (length < bytes.Length)
                    Array.Resize(ref bytes, length);

                rsStream.Bytes = bytes; // assign the byte array to some other object which is declared as a byte array 

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
        return rsStream;
    } // DownloadFileSaveToDisk
```

then the returned object can be used elsewhere.....